# In which uses can I find SharedActivityContext?

Tags: android, delphi, delphi-xe7

SharedActivityContext exist in uses FMX.Helpers.Android for XE6

But for XE7 I can't find SharedActivityContext in uses FMX.Helpers.Android.
Is there another methode of is it moved into another uses?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

It was moved to the new `Androidapi.Helpers` unit.